# Android thread won't stop running

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a basic asynchronous task that performs a web request.  The thread is not contained in a loop or anything, it performs the request and returns from `run()`.  When I try to execute another request, using that thread, I get an exception thrown because the thread is already running.  I've searched around a lot on this site for answers, but all that seems to come up is stopping threads that are in a loop, basically forcing the thread to return.

Should I just put the request code in the thread into a loop that waits on some kind of flag from the main thread to tell it to go ahead and execute again? like:

```
public void run()
{
    while ( threadIsStillRunning )
    {
        while ( !threadShouldExecute )
        {
            //Sleep the thread
        }
        //Execute the request

    }
}
```

EDIT:
Ok, well here's the thread (this is contained in one of my class objects-WebServiceHelper):

```
private Thread executeRequest = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //Meat of the code
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

I then have another class method in the same class(WebServiceHelper):

```
private volatile boolean isRunning = false;
public void Execute(WebServiceHandler handler)
{
    while ( isRunning )
    {
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    isRunning = true;
    r = handler;
    executeRequest.start();
}
```

where r is just an interface object that I use to perform callbacks to the object performing the request.

Then in my main activity (the one that requested the thread execution i have this:

```
private Runnable getSiteData = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        mWebServiceHelper.SetMethod("GetSiteData");
        mWebServiceHelper.Execute(mySiteHelper);
    }
};

public void downloadDidFinish(List<Map<String, String>> data)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TeamList.StoreTeams(data );

    mHandler.post(getSiteData);
}
```

`downloadDidFinish` gets called by the thread above upon completion, I then perform another request right after as you can see.  The crash is happening when I try to call `Execute` again on the `WebServiceHelper` and start the thread again.

Comment: You will have an easier time getting assistance with real code that raises real exceptions with real stack traces, all of which you supply in the question. Abstract things like "When I try to execute another request, using that thread, I get an exception thrown because the thread is already running" are difficult for others to analyze, because we are not mind readers, and therefore do not necessarily recognize the specific exception or understand how you are trying to reuse the thread.

Comment: We need more context to be able to help you here. Some kind of debugging info would help.

Comment: Added some code into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynctask is very useful to manage your threads.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
https://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Here is an example:  http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/

Comment: Doesn't answer my question about the thread not stopping, but switching solved my problem